# UK visit visa: what to specify for monthly income when income varies?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, turkish-citizens

Currently applying for a 2 week visit visa for my Turkish fiance. He works and helps run his family business all year this job is paid cash which my fiance then deposits into his bank on payday and gets a printed and stamped bank statement.

The issue is the pay sometimes varies as it does depend on what the cafe makes each month. Some months its 600 TRY to 800 TRY and mostly it is 1000 TRY. He keeps some in his bank as savings and the rest is spent on living, bills etc.

We were going to include a cover letter explaining this and also his pay etc will be explained in his employment letter. The question on the application asks how much the applicant gets paid monthly we are unsure what to put as some months vary.

Comment: I would calculate an average.  Add up the total pay for the previous three years and divide by 36, or something like that.  Whatever you do, include an explanation of your calculation at the end of the application.  If something is unclear, they will suspect you of being deceptive, which will result in an immediate refusal and make future applications much more difficult.  Transparency is crucial.

Comment: He has only started working since the beginning of this year when the cafe (family buisness) opened. Before then he was in the army doing his national service. I was going to do a cover letter bulletpointing each month what was paid into the account as his bank now shows as 1,500tl which is saved from his wages. I am just so confused how to do this

Comment: Your plan seems reasonable. Obviously if he's only been in his present line of work for 9 or 10 months you should average his earnings for just that 9-or-10-month period. There are relevant questions and answers under [tag:proof-provenance-of-funds].

Comment: Aplogies I'm new to this - ok it is roughly an adverage of 800-900tl a month what he does is keep some also for living around 300tl per month. I'm finding it hard to put into writing as he doesn't use his card for spending really and some of the 1,500tl in his account is from what he has saved it's just explain this I'm finding difficult

Comment: @phoog right for me also, go ahead and write it up :)

Answer (score 2):

List the average for the past 6 months and include the details about his type of employment in the cover letter. As long as you don't misrepresent the facts (e.g. by using the maximum salary value in the application), it should be fine.

Also see this great post about providing [bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) when applying for UK visas. As long as there's stable payments coming into his account every month it should be fine.